# Detect custom URL on click of link in web view

Tags: android, webview, observers

In my Android application that has to work with API Level 23 till 27, I'm showing a web view with my proper website URL. When the page is loading, I'm able to observe "shouldOverrideUrlLoading, onPageStarted and onPageFinished" successfully.

But in my website, there's a custom URL that has to be handled in my app. My custom URL is like "tvloc://lat:123.45,lng:456.78". When I'm clicking the custom url link in web view, its not calling any observers.

 How can I solve the problem to detect custom URL. Here's my code:

```
        client = new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            Log.v(TAG, "shouldOverrideUrlLoading -> " + url);
            return checkURL(url);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
            String url = request.getUrl().toString();
            return checkURL(url);
        }

        private boolean checkURL(String url) {
            Log.v(TAG, "shouldOverrideUrlLoading -> " + url);
            if (url.startsWith(urlPrefix)) {

                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            Log.v(TAG, "onPageStarted -> " + url);
            if (!progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                progressDialog.show();
            }
        }

        @SuppressLint("JavascriptInterface")
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);

            if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }

            Log.v(TAG, "onPageFinished -> " + url);
        }
    };

    webView.setWebViewClient(client);
```

Comment: `tvloc://lat:123.45,lng:456.78` doesn't seems like a URL . make sure the `href` link is ok . Is it working on web ?

Comment: @ADM, Its a custom URL as I said in the title

Answer (score 0):

The `WebView` probably doesn't detect "tvloc://lat:123.45,lng:456.78" as a URL. Try changing to something like "http://tvloc=lat:123.45,lng:456.78".